# Difference between stroke and fill?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, core-graphics

What's the difference between Stroke and Fill drawing in graphics context (iPhone SDK)

Answer (score 26):

Stroke is line drawing, Fill is "colouring in" (for want of a better term).

So in the case of a shape (like a circle), the stroke is the border (circumference) and the fill is the body (interior).

[image]

Comment: So when the shape is open like, say a straight line, fill does nothing?

Comment: @user1598390 indeed that's the case.

Comment: What would be then BorderColor and BackgroundColor?

Answer (score 14):

**Stroke** only draws stuff on the border of the path.

**Fill** only draws stuff in the interior of the path.

[image]

Comment: So when the shape is open like, say a straight line, fill does nothing?